# Combine columns joined?

Tags: mysql

Ok the query takes info from three tables in order to get the account details, from the admin, employee and client problem is that my because someone only exists in either Admin_Agency, Agency_Employee or Client table I end up with a bunch of columns containing NULLS, see below.

**Here I would like to somehow like combine the following columns so there are no NULL columns:**

Client.First_Name, Admin_Agency.Admin_First_Name and Admin_Agency.Admin_First_Name 
into First_Name

Client.Last_Name, Admin_Agency.Admin_Last_Name and Admin_Agency.Admin_Last_Name 
into Last_Name

And Lastly all the columns named "Profile_Pic".

Can this be done?

```
+--------------------+---------------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| User_Comment       | Time_Stamp          | Account_ID | Admin_First_Name | Admin_Last_Name | Profile_Pic | First_Name | Last_Name | Profile_Pic | First_Name | Last_Name | Profile_Pic |
+--------------------+---------------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Lorem ipsum dolor  | 2012-03-21 23:40:15 |         18 | Fredric          | Beskoski        | 002.jpg     | NULL       | NULL      | NULL        | NULL       | NULL      | NULL        |
+--------------------+---------------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Lorem ipsum dolor  | 2012-04-21 23:40:05 |         20 | NULL             | NULL            | NULL        | Alan       | James     | 032.jpg     | NULL       | NULL      | NULL        |
+--------------------+---------------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
| Lorem ipsum dolor  | 2012-05-24 21:40:12 |         21 | NULL             | NULL            | NULL        | NULL       | NULL      | NULL        | David      | Calson    | 044.jpg     |
+--------------------+---------------------+------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Notice above that Admin_First_Name, Admin_Last_Name and Profile_Pic is filled the but rest are NULL.

The query:

```
SELECT 
    Comments.User_Comment, Comments.Time_Stamp, Account.Account_ID,
    Admin_Agency.Admin_First_Name, Admin_Agency.Admin_Last_Name, Admin_Agency.Profile_Pic,
    Agency_Employee.First_Name, Agency_Employee.Last_Name, Agency_Employee.Profile_Pic,
    Client.First_Name, Client.Last_Name, Client.Profile_Pic

FROM Comments
    LEFT JOIN Account ON (Account.Account_ID = Comments.Account_ID_FK4)
    LEFT JOIN Admin_Agency ON (Account.Account_ID = Admin_Agency.Agency_ID)
    LEFT JOIN Agency_Employee ON (Account.Account_ID = Agency_Employee.Employee_ID)
    LEFT JOIN Client ON (Account.Account_ID = Client.Client_ID)

WHERE Comments.Design_ID_FK = 5
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set first priority to check which one first (either values from client or admin). example  if you want check first value exist from client like :

```
select if(Client.First_Name is Null,Admin_Agency.Admin_First_Name,Client.First_Name) 
as first_name ,...   //Same for other columns
From ...
Joins....
Where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Left or Right outer joins can give you nulls.

Inner joins might give you fewer rows, but none of the rows will introduce any nulls from the "join".